# Positive Or Negative - If Statements

Tags: c#, console

Alright so in the book im reading its telling me to write a program that asks the user for two multiplication numbers and then it will print out whether the result should be positive or negative.

The rule is that i cannot take two numbers and multiply them, and then check if the result is greater than or less than zero. Instead if the two numbers have the same sign (both positive or both negative) the result is positive. If they have different signs, the result is negative.

I did it like this ( also i added int anresult = first * second;   <- do i need that?) because if i remove it it still works, but the book wants it in multiplication. so im not sure if that piece of code is doing anything at all

```
            Console.WriteLine("Enter First Nuumber: ");
        string firstAsString = Console.ReadLine();
        int first = Convert.ToInt32(firstAsString);


        Console.WriteLine("Enter Second Nuumber: ");
        string secondAsString = Console.ReadLine();
        int second = Convert.ToInt32(secondAsString);



        int anresult = first * second;

        if (first >= 0 && second > 0 || first < 0 && second < 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Your number will be Positive");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Your number will be negative");


        Console.ReadLine();
```

But the book did it like this

```
            Console.WriteLine("Enter First Nuumber: ");
        string firstAsString = Console.ReadLine();
        int first = Convert.ToInt32(firstAsString);


        Console.WriteLine("Enter Second Nuumber: ");
        string secondAsString = Console.ReadLine();
        int second = Convert.ToInt32(secondAsString);


        bool firsNumberPositive;
        bool secondNumberPositive;


        if (first > 0) {
            firsNumberPositive = true;
        }
        else
        {
            firsNumberPositive = false;
        }

        if (second > 0)
        {
            secondNumberPositive = true;
        }
        else
        {
            secondNumberPositive = false;
        }

        if (firsNumberPositive && secondNumberPositive || !firsNumberPositive && !secondNumberPositive)
            Console.WriteLine("Answer Is Positive");
        else
            if (!firsNumberPositive && secondNumberPositive || firsNumberPositive && !secondNumberPositive) 
        Console.WriteLine("Answer Is Negative");

        Console.ReadLine();
```

isnt my way the same as the books way? because the book shows

```
  if (first > 0) {
                firsNumberPositive = true;
            }
```

which is using the numbers just like i am to display positive and negative

heres mine, same thing?..

```
 if (first >= 0 && second > 0 || first < 0 && second < 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Your number will be Positive");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Your number will be negative");
```

Comment: Test your code with 5 for first and 0 for second

Comment: nono, im wondering if my way is just like the books, so basically its finding the positive negative by checking the first number and second number to see if its a - or a +

because im not supposed to check by the result.
so i cant check if i put 2 and -5 and the answer is -3, my code cant be checking -3 to check if its negative

so im wondering if my code at the top is checkijng by the sign and not the end result

Comment: The code in the book is horrible - it would be much cleaner to use `bool firstNumberPositive = first > 0;`. Any time you see `if` branches assigning (or returning) true and false without doing anything else, it can be improved.

Comment: You basically re-invented the XOR operator.  Quicker is `first < 0 ^ second >= 0`  Ignore the book.

Answer (score 1):

The solution presented in the book doesn't consider the condition where the input is 0, so it will behave differently than the code you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution does not output the same result as the one in the book. Just try it with both `first` and `second` 0. Your code will say the result is negative while the book's solution will say it is positive.

In my opinion, 0 is neither a positive nor negative number and should be treated separately. So here's my solution:

```
if (first == 0 || second == 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("The result is 0");
} else if ((first > 0) != (second > 0)) { // here, it might look a little weird but I'm just checking whether the signs are the same.
    Console.WriteLine("The result is negative");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("The result is positive");
}
```